# How to program a button to switch pages?

Tags: android, eclipse, button, layout

I have an android application project in eclipse with two layouts. One has a button, and I need a bit of help to program that button to switch layouts to the other page. I have looked at countless other threads, but nothing seems to be working. If someone could supply a foolproof method for doing this,  I would be very grateful. :D

Comment: Can you post one among the countless tries you have made ? That gonna make this question beautiful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better yet, use only one activity and then switch views as needed.

public class Activity1 extends Activity {

```
     View firstV = null;
   View secondV = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    firstV = inflate(R.layout.my_xml_1);
    secondV = inflate(R.layout.my_xml_2);
    setContentView(firstV);
    secondV = inflate(R.layout.my_xml_2);
    addContentView secondB


            findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v){
                     firstv.setVisible ( View.invisible};
                     secondv.setVisible ( View.visible};


                 }
            });

    }
```

Comment: How exactly does that work, is there a tutorial or a video that you can link that explains more about this?

Comment: I tried to edit it to make it more obvious, but several people rejected the edit. Didn't even know that could happen.  sorry this is my last post here. this place sucks.

Comment: Checkout layoutinflator and addContentView, they are both stock Andoid as is setting a views Visibility. This approach is a lot more managible than multiple activities. I cant put a linefeed into this box, another -1 for SO and don't get me started on the answer UI. Hopefully one of the HTML guys on this site won't remove my answer because it has words they don't know.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really just doing one of the most basic things in android development...using an intent to move from one activity to another activity.

Check out some tutorials, it'll serve you better in the long run:  http://developer.android.com/training/index.html http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html

Edit - So it's more of an answer...

Activity1

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_xml);

                findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v){
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                         startActivity(intent);
                     }
                });

        }
```

Activity2

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_xml_2);
        }
```

my_xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my_xml_2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Submersed, I tried this, and loaded the application onto my device, and all was well until I tapped the button. After I did that, the app crashed. I believe that the error has occurred on line 60 in my second java file, but I could be mistaken. I have included the link to the logcat info, so that maybe you could say where the error is coming from. http://pastebin.com/WH8kmKPQ

Comment: Did you add the activities to your manifest?

Comment: Yes they are both in the manifest, but it is still throwing the NPE

Comment: It works for me...Also, there shouldn't be a 60 line second java file if you used exactly what I posted.  Finally, from the stack trace, it looked like you may have your components named incorrectly in the manifest i.e. sehej.android.doge.MainGameActivity